# What is an equivalent of a parabola (Euclidean metric) in Voronoi sweep for Manhattan metric??

Tags: geometry, algorithms

How do we build Voronoi on Manhattan metric (l1 norm)? Using sweep line (same as for Euclidean)? If yes, then what is the equivalent for a parabola abstraction during a sweep line (e.g what arc shape defines equidistance from a point to an arc and from an arc to a sweep line)?
[pictorial representation of a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3YTN.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any examples? The Manhattan metric is not isotropic, which means that the answer will depend on the direction of the line. Try drawing it for the lines $x = 0$, $x = y$ and $y = 0$. If you have problems, give us some more information about them.